# Laravel Take Value from dropdown on blade

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade, dropdown

im trying to pass date from the dropdown to a route that is defined id/year/month. anyway with this code i always get 1990 and 12, it ignores what is selected in the dropdown.

```
<div class="col-span-12 box">
                    <div class="flex items-center p-5 border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-dark-5">
                        <h2 class="text-lg font-medium truncate mr-5">{{ __('messages.download-file') }}</h2>
                     <div class="input-form">
                                    <label>Month</label><span class="ml-1 text-theme-6">*</span>
                                    <select class="input border w-full mt-2" name="month">
                                        <option value="">{{ __('messages.select') }}</option>
                                        @php
                                            $months = range(date('M'), date('12'));
                                        @endphp
                                        @foreach ($months as $month)
                                            <option value="{{ $month }}">{{ $month }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                     <div class="input-form">
                                    <label>{{ __('messages.year') }}</label><span class="ml-1 text-theme-6">*</span>
                                    <select class="input border w-full mt-2" name="year">
                                        <option value="">{{ __('messages.select') }}</option>
                                        @php
                                            $years = range(date('Y'), date('1990'));
                                        @endphp
                                        @foreach ($years as $year)
                                            <option value="{{ $year }}">{{ $year }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <form method="GET" action="{{ route('admin.users.filterbydate', [$user->id, $year, $month])}}">
                                <button type="submit" class="w-8 h-8 sm:w-10 sm:h-10 block bg-theme-1 text-white rounded-full flex-none flex items-center justify-center mr-5">
                                    <i data-feather="Filter" class="w-4 h-4"></i>
                                </button>
                                </form>
                    </div>
```

i want to fix from blade, if i define

```
@php 
$year="2"; 
@endphp
```

it passes 2 as year, so info is good passed to route. issue is not taken from the dropdown. always take 1990/12 as default

Comment: Your `<selects>` are not inside the form so they won't get submitted. From your loops (`@foreach`), the last value of `$year` is 1990, the last value of `$month` is 12. Either use JS to get the selected values or include your selects in your form and redirect to the correct URL from your controller

Comment: i upped the form opening to first and put the action on the send button. now is working like a charm!

Comment: also now is redirected to //admin/users/2396?month=3&year=2007
how i can make to go ..2396/3/2007

Comment: Redirected from where? Get the submitted values in your controller method, then [redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/redirects) to wherever you want using those values

Comment: my route is admin/users/{id}/{year}/{month}, problem is with that the generated patch instead being on same format. Should be admin/users/2396/2007/3, but the generated link is  //admin/users/2396?month=3&year=2007 , how i can modify code to go to correct route.

Comment: Read my previous comment. Or use Javascript to "redirect" to your desired url. Good luck

Comment: Of course, is what i did. but i have 2 routes
one is admin/users/{id}
and other is admin/users/{id}/{year}/{month},
problem is with output from form always goes to first one, but when i wrote on address bar admin/users/2020/2018/04 it goes to correct function on controller..
i dont know why the action helper write month=06 instea 06 directly, this is my question. i also tried with a href, but as before takes the first value from my foreach loop